# How to delete all nodes of same value from linklist/Queue

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, queue

I have been trying hard to resolve this however yet not succeed I have data structs as follow (which actually is very complex I just simplifies for discussion) :

```
typedef struct node{
 struct node* next;
  void* arg;
}node_t;

typedef struct queue{
node_t* head;
node_t* tail;
}queue_t;

addQ(queue_t*ptr , int data)
{
    queue_t* q = ptr;
    node_t * n = malloc(sizeof(*n));

    n->arg = data;
    n->next = NULL;

    if(NULL == q->head){
       q->head = q->tail = n;
       return ;
    }
    q->tail->next = n;
    q->tail = q->tail->next;
}
```

Now I want to delete node of same value ( I have tried couple ways however yet not succeed ) , Just consider this sequence for reference:

```
addQ(q, 12);
addQ(q, 12);
addQ(q,  4);
addQ(q, 12);
addQ(q, 12);
addQ(q, 14);
addQ(q, 12);
addQ(q, 12);
```

I want to Delete all the nodes with value 12.

Comment: It always helps to show one or two of the ways you tried.

Comment: just a simple query is it a queue or a eneral linked list?, if its a queue honestly you should not even attempt to delete any node of your choice, dequeue is the option you must be using i suppose, any ways is it a linked list ?

Comment: @duke, Sure I can post my version as well however it is not working yet.

Comment: @udy , it is a queue and I want to delete all node's of same value from it.

Comment: @SelectCall Showing what you tried is generally better for [so] questions, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: what about iterating from head to tail, killing entries that match your query? since your datastructure is essentially a linked list, that shouldn't be much of an issue.

Answer (score 4):

This solution got a bit hairy with the double pointers, but I still like it, as it doesn't have to special case what node (first vs the rest) is being checked.  I tried to put enough comments in to describe what's going on, but it's still hard for even me to follow at first glance.

PSEUDOCODE..

```
Queue * q;
VALUE = 12;

// double pointer so we can treat the queue head and subsequent nodes the same.
//   because they are both pointers to Node.  
// Otherwise you'd have to have code that says if the one you're removing is the 
// first element of the queue, adjust q->head, otherwise adjust node->next.  
// This lets you not special case the deletion.
Node ** node_ptr = &(q->head)

while (*node_ptr != null) {
    if ((**node_ptr).arg == VALUE) {
        // store off the matching node to be freed because otherwise we'd orphan
        // it when we move the thing pointing to it and we'd never be able to free it
        Node * matched_node = *node_ptr;

        // when we find a match, don't move where node_ptr points, just change the value it
        // points to to skip the matched node and point to the one after it (or null)
        *node_ptr = matched_node->next; 
        free(matched_node);
    } else {
        // otherwise, nothing was deleted, so skip over that node to the next one.
        // remember, **node_ptr is a double dereference, so we're at the node
        // now, so then we grab the address of the non-matching node's next value so it can be
        // potentially changed in the next iteration
        node_ptr = &((**node_ptr).next);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is considerably cleaner than it may first appear. it essentially scans the list, keeping the *address* of the pointer that may be referencing a potential node match in `node_ptr`. On a match, that node is unlinked and the hole it leaves filled by storing its 'next' in the pointer that referenced it in the first place. The only potential problem is see is a tail-fixup, but the idea should be clear, and is *very* memory efficient, requiring no node duplications whatsoever.

Comment: I'm still cleaning it up.  Truly, that much pointer stuff gets me turned around for loops, even though I've been doing it for a long time.

Comment: this is what I was thinking, thanks for the detail explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a function that obtains and removes the next item in the queue, let's call it `getQ(q)`, then you could achieve your goal without even having to know the internals of the queue, by just using the operations you already have, e.g. something like (this won't work because `arg` is a `void`, but the logic should be clear):

```
node_t *n;
queue_t *q2 = initialiseQ();
while (n = getQ(q)) {
    if (n->arg != 12) {
        addQ(q2,n);
    }
}
free(q);
q = q2;
```

Comment: Yeah i have funcation which remove from the head and can add to the queue and can dequeue aswell , btw are you suggesting another queue ? isn't it an expensive when you are expecting hundred of thousands operations??

Comment: moving pointers around isn't really a big deal.  If you were to fully-reallocate the nodes and then deallocate the old ones, that would be very bad.  I mean, you're traversing the pointers of all the nodes anyhow, so making it shift pointers around isn't a big deal.  But it can be done inline.

Comment: Both @xaxxon's point and Select Call's point are correct, I think. The current implementation of `addQ()` allocates a node each time, which could be an issue if it was done hundreds of thousands of times. However, an alternative implemention of `addQ()` that took an existing `node` as a parameter and just moved the pointers around (as proposed by xaxxon) would be easy to write (indeed, the current `addQ()` could allocate the node and then just call the new `addQ_node()` with the new node as a parameter) and very quick to run.

Comment: I just added a solution where the nodes are removed in-place.  It's not as clear exactly what is going on, but I think it goes the direction you were thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an inline solution that doesn't use double pointers.  It has to treat the first element and subsequent elements differently since the pointer to adjust changes from the queue structure to the node structure.

Also, for subsequent nodes, you have to track the trailing node, since that's where you have to make the adjustment as you delete the matching node.

```
Queue * q;
VALUE = 12;


// handle the case where the first node matches.
// you have to adjust the q's head pointer
// delete from the head and set a new head node until a non-matching head is found
while (q->head != NULL && q->head->arg == VALUE) {
  Node * matching_node = q->head;
  q->head = q->head->next;
  free(matching_node);
}

// if there is more than one node left, need to check the subsequent nodes
if (q->head != NULL && q->head->next != NULL) {

    Node * node_ptr = q->head->next;
    Node * prev_node_ptr = q->head;

    while (node_ptr != NULL) {
        if (node_ptr->arg == VALUE) {
            Node * matched_node = node_ptr; // don't orphan it before it's freed

            // You don't move the prev_node pointer since that doesn't change when a match
            //   is found.  Only the node_ptr, which skips to the next one. 
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
            free(matched_node);            
        } else {
            prev_node_ptr = node_ptr;
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah Thank you once again .just found where I screw things :)

Comment: was there a problem with the answer for removing the checkmark?

Comment: Just tried as my version is more like this looks like it has bug , however other version works fine.

Comment: Hrmm.. I'm not seeing any problems, but of course this isn't actual code.  was it crashing or just not deleting things or deleting too much?

Comment: it is skipping first two nodes and deleting other two nodes which it suppose not to do. I will debug this in morning. thank you once again for your input.

Comment: I updated the code a little.  The free() call was wrong by saying free(node_ptr) now it says free(matched_node).  Though this shouldn't have caused the type of problem you saw.